# How to fix "SystemError: <built-in function 'name'> returned NULL without setting an error" in Python C Extension

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

Tools: Python3.7 (64 bit), Visual C++ 10.0
I am trying to create a C extension for Python. To start, I am testing a simple C code which prints a string and invokes the Sleep() function inside a *for* loop. However, when I make a simple call to this C function, named gen_nums, from Python, I get the following error:

**"SystemError: built-in function gen_nums returned NULL without setting an error"**

I think the problem is with the Sleep() function; deleting the "Sleep(1000)" part or placing it before "printf("Printed from C thread...\n")" eliminates this error. I looked over the documentation for Sleep() but couldn't find anything useful.

C Code:

```
#include <Python.h>

static void gen_nums() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Printed from C thread...\n");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
static PyMethodDef gen_numsmethods[] = {
    {"gen_nums", gen_nums, METH_VARARGS, "This is a threading test"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
static struct PyModuleDef threadmod = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "threadrun",
    "This is a thread test module",
    -1,
    gen_numsmethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_threadrun(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&threadmod);
}
```

Python Call:

```
threadrun.gen_nums() \\ the C module is called threadrun
```

The result should be:
"Printed from C thread..." 10 times, with a 1 second interval between each statement.

However, the program prints the statement 10 times and then displays the aforementioned error.

Comment: that's not *at all* how a C extension function needs to be written. Please read the [tutorial again](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example) and refer to it in further questions.

Comment: Most relevant information to answer this question is in the section 1.1 and 1.2, I cannot write a more perfect answer than to rip the entire text of sections 1.1 and 1.2 here verbatim, so it doesn't help much now.

Comment: I had actually properly created a C extension, just uploaded the entire C code now. However, what I don't understand is why the "gen_nums" returns NULL only when Sleep() is included.

Comment: Ok then please do ask it! You asked "how to fix"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error is this: Python extension functions **must** have a certain C prototype:

```
PyObject *func(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
```

The method slots contain function pointers of type

```
PyObject *(*)(Pyobject *, PyObject *)
```

The old way was to *forcibly cast the function* to this pointer type to be stored into the method slot. The explicit cast will silence the error of conversion of `void (*)()` to `PyObject *(*)(Pyobject *, PyObject *)`. The conversion is valid, but needs an explicit cast. **If an explicit cast is not there, then a C compiler *must* issue a diagnostics message**.

Your code does not have an explicit cast, hence you must get a warning for

```
{"gen_nums", gen_nums, METH_VARARGS, "This is a threading test"},
```

In any case, *if there were an explicit cast*, the program would still be a correct program up until when Python tries to invoke your function `gen_nums()`, because Python will do so **as if** its prototype were

```
PyObject *gen_nums(PyObject *, PyObject *);
```

**Now** the C standard says that while *everything was fine up to this point*, from now on the **behaviour** of the program is **undefined**, because [C11 6.3.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8):

> 8. A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.**

Your function returns **void**, i.e. nothing at all, yet you ask "why it returns `NULL` only when `Sleep()` is in there. The reason is "undefined behaviour".

---

As for how to *fix this*, please do read and understand the [Chapter 1 of 1. Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example) - there are plenty of details in there, but everything needed to fix this simple function is detailed in there. If you get stuck please *do* ask further questions but do refer to the documentation in questions.

The fix for *that* function would be to write it as

```
static PyObject *gen_nums(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Printed from C thread...\n");
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```